# Remmina does't work correctly

Tags: server, windows, 22.04, remote-desktop, remmina

I want to connect windows server from Remmina (Ubuntu 22).
But occurs error when I use it. Please help me.
Thanks

```
[13:34:54:620] [23676:23700] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 131
[13:34:54:620] [23676:23700] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 0
[13:34:55:391] [23676:23700] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_connect_tls:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_TLS_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020008]
[13:35:21:531] [23676:23715] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 131
[13:35:21:531] [23676:23715] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 0
[13:35:21:799] [23676:23715] [WARN][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Error: HYBRID_REQUIRED_BY_SERVER
[13:35:21:799] [23676:23715] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Protocol Security Negotiation Failure
[13:35:21:799] [23676:23715] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_client_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_SECURITY_NEGO_CONNECT_FAILED [0x0002000C]
[13:35:21:799] [23676:23715] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to Mint 21

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 only uses OpenSSL 3.0, does your Windows server support that? The errors seem to indicate an SSL issue (protocol security negotiation or connection failure)

Comment: what kind of remote server are you trying to connect? Is it windows?

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193364/remmina-no-longer-working-cannot-connect-to-rdp-server-localhost)